# Calculate rate of change of Pandas Dataframe from Min and Max column values with groupby column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below:

```
NAME,VAL1,VAL2
AAA,27,678
BBB,45,744
CCC,34,275
AAA,29,932
CCC,47,288
BBB,24,971
AAA,16,468
BBB,90,982
CCC,68,751
AAA,23,254
CCC,87,575
CCC,63,364
```

Need to calculate for Every Name,

```
Result_Val1 = ((Max of Val1 - Min of Val1)/Min of Val1) 
Result_Val2 = ((Max of Val2 - Min of Val2)/Min of Val2)
```

Result Should look like:

```
NAME,Result_Val1,Result_Val2
AAA,0.81,2.67
BBB,2.75,0.32
CCC,1.56,1.73
```

Comment: Are you using `pandas` here... if so - you should [edit] to include that as a tag and you don't need the list-comprehension tag here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `groupby` with some arithmetic afterwards should do.

```
v = df.groupby('NAME').agg(['max', 'min'])

mx = v.xs('max', level=1, axis=1)
mn = v.xs('min', level=1, axis=1)
(mx - mn) / mn

          VAL1      VAL2
NAME                    
AAA   0.812500  2.669291
BBB   2.750000  0.319892
CCC   1.558824  1.730909
```

---

Let's try an alternative using a custom function:

```
def scaled_ptp(x):
    mn = x.min()
    return (x.max() - mn) / mn

df.groupby('NAME').agg(scaled_ptp)
```

You can do the same thing in one line but you'd need an assignment expression in python3.8:

```
df.groupby('NAME').agg(lambda x: (x.max() - y := x.min()) / y)
```

```
          VAL1      VAL2
NAME                    
AAA   0.812500  2.669291
BBB   2.750000  0.319892
CCC   1.558824  1.730909
```

Comment: Whether it can be executed in a single line to handle huge dataframe with more than 2500k rows ?

Comment: @Pravat Umm, lesser lines != better code. This is pretty fast for your problem, I'd say. And 2500K is 2.5 million?

Comment: I am new to Python. Can you please help me with the procedure of assigning expression in python 3.7/3.8

Comment: @Pravat You'll have to wait a year for python3.8 to come out. Until then, you're stuck with the other two options I've given you, which, most importantly, work.

Comment: Ohh Ok. no problem. Thanks for the quick reply.